# Get the columns of the first row?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-3.0

I have the following code and I want the function `getCol1Col2` returns tuple of `Col1, Col2` instead of `Linq.IQueryable<>`. How to write it? This is newbie question.

And how to returns none if there is no row found in the database table?

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Net
open System.IO

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;">

let getFirstCol1Col2 =
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
    let query = query { 
        for row in db.MyTable do 
        where (row.ID = 1) 
        select (row.Col1, row.Col2) }
    query //.... Need to return the tuple of Col1, Col2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard query operator `headOrDefault` which returns the first result or default value. Sadly, the default value of tuple will be `null` (I think), so this will be unsafe. You could return an option type, because the default value of an option type is `None`:

```
let query = 
  query { for row in db.MyTable do 
          where (row.ID = 1) 
          select (Some(row.Col1, row.Col2))
          headOrDefault }
```

Alternatively, you can use [this nice extension](http://fssnip.net/go) which adds `headOrNone` that does exactly what you want - returns `Some(col1, col2)` if there are some rows or `None` otherwise:

```
let query = 
  query { for row in db.MyTable do 
          where (row.ID = 1) 
          select (Some(row.Col1, row.Col2))
          headOrNone }
```

Comment: Thanks, curiously why f# cannot do `query.ToList().FirstOrDefault()` like c# for IQueryable?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : It can -- did you `open System.Linq`?

Comment: doing `ToList().FirstOrDefault()` is a bad idea if there are multiple results - it will mean that you first download everything to memory and then return the first one. If you wanted to do this in memory, you could as well use `Seq.toList` and pattern matching (e.g.)